# Localhost always show Welcome to nginx!

Tags: nginx

I was working fine on my projects. After restarting my machine, I tried to access a local project and I get the message "Welcome to nginx!" even if I want to open phpmyadmin.

What is the problem and how I can restore my environment? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/134666/83046

Comment: I followed it but still get the same message.

Comment: We'd need more information about your configurations, etc. to solve this.  Note however that 12.04 is pretty old at this point, so you should focus on upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

I don't forget refresh your browser with `ctrl + F5`